# How do I establish the average grade for all students?

Tags: python, class, oop, average, class-method

I have tried to make a method where I can show the entire average of all students. As you can see in my code, I tried to create an empty list (class-variable) to store the average grade of each student. In my **init** method I have described that every new student who joins them saves their average grade in the "marklist" list so that I can later define a method that gives me the overall average grade of all students. In order to be able to do this, however, I have to divide the sum of all grade points by the number of students. However, it doesn't work in my program. I'm not quite sure which method to use, whether I can do this with the staticmethod or whether it works with a normal method. I have defined a method "mark_avarage_students_all" that performs the division mentioned. However, performing this method gives me an error because of missing an self argument. Anyone know how I can ultimately output this grade point average for all students? Thanks in advance

Here is my Code:

```
class Students:

    #class variables
    num_of_students = 0
    #use later to add up all marks from all student
    marklist = []

    def __init__(self, first, last, age, catalognumber, markaverage):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
        self.catalognumber = catalognumber
        self.markaverage = markaverage
        self.averageall = Students.marklist.append(self.markaverage)

        Students.num_of_students += 1

    def std_description(self):
        print('My Name is {} {}, I am {} years old.'.format(self.first, self.last, self.age))
        print('My Catalog Number is {} and I have a Mark-average of {}'.format(self.catalognumber, self.markaverage))
        print("")

    @classmethod
    def convert_str(cls, str_std):
        first, last, age, catalognumber, markaverage = str_std.split('-') 
        return cls(first, last, age, catalognumber, markaverage)   

    #calculate the mark average of all students --> sum(marklist) / sum(num_of_students)
    def mark_average_students_all(self):
        return sum(Students.marklist) / Students.num_of_students

if __name__ == '__main__':
    std_1 = 'Jill-Janson-18-20-1.6'
    convert_std_1 = Students.convert_str(std_1)
    convert_std_1.std_description()

    Students.mark_average_students_all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined it as an instance method, but called it from the class.  Therefore, the call comes without the implicit `self` argument.  Either call it from an instance, or change the definition to match your usage.  The better option is to match the usage: simply declare it as `@classmethod` and dump the `self` parameter (which you don't use).

Comment: if I do the classmethod, which parameter do i pass (apart from the cls)

Comment: There is no other parameter to pass.  The class attributes contain all the data you need, so the `cls` parameter is sufficient for your needs.